# Why is Elasticlunr version 0.9.5 not working with Safari 10.3.3 (14F89) using the code below

Tags: javascript

Using elasticlunr I set up an index as follows:

```
elasticlunr.clearStopWords();
elasticlunr.tokenizer.seperator = /[\s\-\/@]+/;

function indexStops(document) {
  var index = elasticlunr();
  index.pipeline.remove(elasticlunr.stemmer);

  index.setRef('stop_id');
  index.addField('stop_code');
  index.addField('stop_name');
  index.addField('stop_desc');
  index.saveDocument(false);

  var i = 0;
  for (var doc in document) {
    index.addDoc(document[doc]);
    i++;
  }
  return index;
}
```

I then use it as follows:

```
var results = index.search(searchText, {
  bool: "AND",
  expand: true
});
```

On any modern browser other than Safari it works. On Safari IOS 8.4.1 and 9.3.5 it works. On Safari 10.3.3 and modern versions of MAC OS X it does NOT work. It returns results for the occasional value of searchText but most do not return anything.  Two questions

Is there anything in this code snippet that is non standard and effecting the search on modern versions of Safari ?

Are there known problems with elasticlunr and certain browser versions ?

In general I do not have access to javascript debug facilities on apple platforms. However the one time I did the results when there was no match and there should have been could be seen in a debugger to be of the form:

```
results: [{ref: "0", score Nan}, {ref: "1", score Nan},{ref: "2", score Nan} .....etc... ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For something that works on all browsers the solution is to write your own search. If your are not interested in stems or stopwords and have a json object with your data where the keys are the reference it is as simple as

```
var text;
for (var ref in dataAsJson) {
  // text is what you will use when searching for matches
  text = dataAsJson[ref].searchField1 + dataAsJson[ref].searchField2; //etc
  text = text.toLowerCase();
  dataAsJson[ref].search = text; 
}
```

Then the method for searching (which does not kick in until the *searchText* contains at least 3 characters) is

```
function searchStops(dataAsJson, searchText) {
  var matchRefs = [];

  if (dataAsJson == undefined || searchText.length < 3) {
    return matchRefs;
  }

  // Create an array of searchTerms from searchText which are all lowercase. 
  // Split on whitespace
  var terms = searchText.split(/[\s]+/);
  var searchTerms = [];
  for (var i=0; i<terms.length; i++) {
    if (terms[i].length > 0) {
      searchTerms.push(terms[i].toLowerCase());
    }
  }

  var match;
  var search;
  for (var ref in dataAsJson) {
    match = true;
    search = dataAsJson[ref].search;
    for (var i=0; i<searchTerms.length; i++) {
      if (search.indexOf(searchTerms[i]) == -1) {
        // Start by assuming a match, however if any of the terms are
        // not found we do not match
        match = false;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (match) {
      matchRefs.push(ref);        
    }
  }

  return matchRefs;
}
```

I am using this with dataAsJson containing about 8000 lines with have 5-10 words each and have not noticed it as any slower than the equivalent elasticlunr implementation (both cases appears instantaneous to user)